# Understanding IP Information Results

Tags: dns, ip, traceroute

Am trying to understand why some IPs like this one shows results in different country. This below output is from using IP Information function provided by DNSStuff.com. This was a key IP in trace-route where switching/redirecting the route was taken place.

```
IP Information Results for 4.68.110.197

Country           Country Code  Region                City        Latitude   Longitude   ISP    
1- nl             nl            nh                    amsterdam   52.377998  4.906000    level 3 communicatio...    
2- United States  US            not found             not found   38.000000  -97.000000  Level 3 Communicatio...    
3- UNITED STATES  US            DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA  WASHINGTON  38.895111  -77.036369  LEVEL 3 COMMUNICATIO...
```

Using Level 3 (http://ipstats.globalcrossing.net/dotcom/bgp.shtml?region=EUROPE&ip=41.69.107.92) to final destination ends at.

from:

1-USA to final destination ends at.
    3356 8452 8452 8452 8452 8452 24835

```
ge4-12-1000M.ar6.PHX1.gblx.net from err41.lax1.gblx.mgmt.level3.net

  Origin IGP, metric 100, localpref 201, valid, internal

  Community: 3549:2017 3549:30840 (North American; United States) 

  Originator: loop0.ar7.LAX1.gblx.net, Cluster list: 0.0.6.18
```

from 2-Europe:
3356 8452 8452 8452 8452 8452 24835

67.16.147.121 from err41.ams2.gblx.mgmt.level3.net

```
  Origin IGP, metric 100, localpref 201, valid, internal

  Community: 3549:2699 3549:31528 (Europe; Netherlands)

  Originator: loop0.ar9.AMS2.gblx.net, Cluster list: 0.0.6.2

  Originator: loop0.ar7.LAX1.gblx.net, Cluster list: 0.0.6.18
```

Traceroute for 41.69.124.108    Date: Friday 07 November 2014
Hour: 00:27:21 UTC

traceroute to 41.69.124.108 (41.69.124.108), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

1  FMC_SCHNADT_ROUTER (80.92.66.1)  0.231 ms  0.293 ms  0.367 ms

2  80-92-83-199.ip.dclux.com (80.92.83.199)  0.212 ms  0.215 ms  0.217 ms

3  80-92-83-193.ip.dclux.com (80.92.83.193)  0.458 ms  0.451 ms  0.479 ms

4  Port-c.410.asr1.AMS2.gblx.net (64.208.205.149)  0.572 ms  0.647 ms  0.712 ms

5  xe5-0-2-10G.scr3.AMS2.gblx.net (67.17.71.213)  8.498 ms  8.499 ms  8.499 ms

6  ae1.ar9.AMS2.gblx.net (67.16.130.182)  14.864 ms  14.877 ms  15.004 ms

7  4.68.110.197 (4.68.110.197)  10.955 ms  10.956 ms  7.739 ms

8  ae-2-5.edge1.Marseille1.Level3.net (4.69.148.14)  31.239 ms  31.267 ms ae-1-4.edge1.Marseille1.Level3.net (4.69.148.10)  28.165 ms

9  TE-DATA-EGY.edge1.Marseille1.Level3.net (212.73.206.14)  64.640 ms  67.819 ms  67.863 ms

10  * * *

11  host-41.33.197.146.tedata.net (41.33.197.146)  68.072 ms  64.745 ms host-41.33.197.154.tedata.net (41.33.197.154)  68.667 ms

12  * * *

13  * * *

14  * * *

15  * * *

16  * * *

17  * * *

18  * * *

19  * * *

20  * * *

21  * * *

22  * * *

23  * * *

24  * * *

25  * * *

26  * * *

27  * * *

28  * * *

29  * * *

### 30  * * *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a couple other searches, it looks like DNSStuff.com is probably aggregating Geolocation data from 3 different services and displaying the results.  The 3 original source probably just have different data.  All 3 recognize the IP as belonging to Level 3 Communications, however Level 3 is a worldwide company and can move its IPs wherever it needs to.